# How do I redirect users from https://www.example.com to https://example.com?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

I did not purchase a wildcard certificate, but I see a big problem with my setup. When I navigate to https://www.redmeetsblue.org I do not have a certificate, like the one I have for http://redmeetsblue.org

How can I redirect the user, from https://www.redmeetsblue.org to http://redmeetsblue.org without the user noticing that there are certificate problems? Is this possible?

Comment: Question in title is not the same as what you ask for in description...

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. Since your certificate is not valid for www., browser will display a warning *before* following any redirect you set.

Go on and purchase either a separate certificate for www., or one that includes both -www. and naked domain. Note that widcard alone *may* not be enough - *.example.com does not cover example.com, unless example.com is also explicitly enabled in the certificate.

Comment: How about through DNS. Is this possible through some DNS mechanism? or will I be stuck with buying another cert?

Comment: @JZ. Not possible through DNS.

Comment: It is possible with DNS if you delete your www A/CNAME record. If there's no www.yourdomain.com DNS record then users can't open their browsers to www.yourdomain.com. You'll be left with only the naked domain.